# Windows 2012 BitsTransfer

Tags: windows-server-2012, microsoft-bits

I have few servers with Windows 2012, but im not able to use Start-BitsTransfer cmdlet. 
The same cmdlet works fine on Windows server Windows 2012 R2 and 2016. Do you know what should be enabled to in Windows Server 2012?

Start-BitsTransfer -source https://...

Start-BitsTransfer : An error occurred in the secure channel support
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-BitsTransfer -source https://...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartBitsTransferCOMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBitsTransferCommand

Answer (score 1):

I believe WS2012 doesn't contain TLS 1.1/1.2 in its **SecureProtocols** registry key. From [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi):

> The SecureProtocols registry entry that has value 0xA80 for enabling
>   TLS 1.1 and 1.2 will be added in the following paths: 
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings
>
> Per the TLS-SSL Settings article, for TLS 1.1 and 1.2 to be enabled
>   and negotiated on Windows 7, you MUST create the "DisabledByDefault"
>   entry in the appropriate subkey (Client) and set it to "0". These
>   subkeys will not be created in the registry since these protocols are
>   disabled by default.
>
> Create the necessary subkeys for TLS 1.1 and 1.2; create the
>   DisabledByDefault DWORD values and set it to 0 in the following
>   locations:
>
> For TLS 1.1 Registry location:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
>   1.1\Client  DWORD name: DisabledByDefault DWORD value: 0
>
> For TLS 1.2 Registry location:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
>   1.2\Client   DWORD name: DisabledByDefault DWORD value: 0